# Natural sorting of 3-4 characters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting

I have an unsorted list of area postcodes as follows:

```
["E1", "E1C", "E1D", "E10", "E11", "E12", "E2", "E3", "E4", "EC1", "EC1A", "EC1M", "EC1N",
"EC1R", "EC1V", "EC1Y", "EC2", "EC2A", "EC2M", "EC2N", "N1", "N10", "N11", "N12",
"N13", "N2", "NW1", "NW10", "NW2" etc]
```

I'd like to sort them as follows:

```
["E1", "E1C", "E1D", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E10", "E11", "E12", "EC1", "EC1A", "EC1M", "EC1N",
"EC1R", "EC1V", "EC1Y", "EC2", "EC2A", "EC2M", "EC2N", "N1", "N2", "N10", "N11", "N12",
"N13", "NW1", "NW2, "NW10" etc]
```

So to sum up the order of the formats for postcodes beginning with E would be:

- E1
- E1C
- E11
- EC1
- EC1V

Same order for postcodes beginning with N, etc.

What would be the recommended way of sorting such strings? In this case the format of the string is always known, i.e. it will always be 2-4 alphanumberic characters, the first always being a letter.

Should I order the strings by length first and then order within each length group, or is there a more elegant method?

Comment: Are things like N1A2 possible? N12A? etc..

Comment: Yeah, these are the only possible alphanumeric combinations: E1, EC1, EC1V, W1C, SW14

Comment: Could you define the expected order of the array `[E1, EC1, EC1V, W1C, SW14]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use

```
array.sort_by do |str|
  /\A(\w)(\d+)\Z/ === str
  [$1, $2.to_i]
end
```

or, if you have arbitrary sequences of alternating letters and digits,

```
array.sort_by do |str|
  /\A(\D*)(\d*)(\D*)(\d*)\Z/.match(str)[1..-1].reject(&:blank?).collect do |item|
    /\d/ === item ? item.to_i : item
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Although this throws an error `comparison of Array with Array failed`. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: For the array `%w(N1 N10 N11 N2 N20 N21)` it works, can you give me an array that's failing?

Comment: Sorry, I realised this may have to do with the context I'm trying to run it in. If I use it for a newly created array as you said it works. However if I try to run it on @postcodes (from `@postcodes = Area.uniq.pluck(:postcode)`), it throws an error. Apologies if I'm missing something obvious, I'm a bit lost with all this at the moment!

Comment: Also, you can take profit of the database: `Area.select("postcode").distinct.map(&:postcode)` (you won't load the whole list of Areas, just one per postcode)

Comment: So, please can you post a representative selection of the elements you have in your list, and the rules to sort them?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help so far. I updated my initial question to include some more examples, and the expected order of one of the arrays. I also tried to use `Area.select("postcode").distinct.map(&:postcode)`, but this throws error `undefined method 'postcode' for #<Arel::Nodes::Distinct:0x007fdf7739c138>` - and using `Area.uniq.map(&:postcode)` throws `Cannot visit Arel::Nodes::Distinct`. Your suggested method works for a newly created array, but not if I'm trying to use it to sort @postcode as described in my previous comment. Do you have any ideas where the issue might be?

Comment: OK - so this is really strange, but I got the second solution you suggested in your initial answer to work, but only after restarting the server. The first one still fails with `comparison of Array with Array failed`. `Using Area.select("postcode").distinct.map(&:postcode)` still doesn't work either - but I guess figuring this out is an different problem altogether (and probably very particular to my situation), so I'll mark this answer as correct! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a weird way of doing it, but I think this should work:

```
array.sort do |a, b|
  a = a.dup
  b = b.dup

  regex = /(\d+)/
  a.match(regex)
  a_num = $1.to_i
  b.match(regex)
  b_num = $1.to_i

  if a_num > b_num
    a.gsub!(regex, "1")
    b.gsub!(regex, "0")
  elsif a_num < b_num
    a.gsub!(regex, "0")
    b.gsub!(regex, "1")
  end

  a <=> b
end
```